# Testing in-app purchase on a simulator vs device

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have just added in app purcahse on in my app, but I get this error message in the "Run" log:

***W/BillingClient: In-app billing API version 3 is not supported on this device.***

Any ideas why that is? This is what I have implemented in `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.2.1'
```